# Fail first unit test, if running through rake

Tags: ruby, rake

I have [Rakefile](https://github.com/rustyrobot/Murder-traffic/blob/master/Rakefile) in my project.

```
mt_server_dir = File.expand_path('vendor/murder_traffic_server')

Rake::TestTask.new("test_vendor") do |t|
  chdir mt_server_dir
  t.libs = [mt_server_dir]
  t.test_files = Dir["#{mt_server_dir}/tests/test_*"]
  t.warning = true
end
```

When I run tests

```
rake test_vendor
```

First test in the list, always [fail](http://travis-ci.org/#!/rustyrobot/Murder-traffic/builds/69006).

With error.

```
test_ip.rb:55: warning: instance variable @ip not initialized
```

That is mean, not execute setup method in first test.

When I run test directly.

```
ruby test_ip.rb
```

Test is successful.

I tried rename first test to test_zip.rb, and when I running test through rake, test is successful, but first in the list test test_dns.rb is failed.

Who know how fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked out the source code of your app on Github.

Your `test_ip.rb` file defines `class TestIp < Test::Unit::TestCase`, as it should. However, your `test_dns.rb` file **also** defines `class TestIp < Test::Unit::TestCase`, whereas it should define `class TestDns`. Since that file also has `def setup`, that setup method overrides the `test_ip` one. This is why you see this error:

```
/home/dylan/dev/Murder-traffic/vendor/murder_traffic_server/tests/test_dns.rb:7: warning: method redefined; discarding old setup
/home/dylan/dev/Murder-traffic/vendor/murder_traffic_server/tests/test_ip.rb:7: warning: previous definition of setup was here
```

So, fix the class declaration in your `test_dns.rb` file and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you! It seems I need some sleep :)